# A online community banned me

Tags: website

there is a specific online forum, that banned me two month ago. Today, I created a new account and they banned the new account again.

How does a website know who I am?
Where does this website get the data from?

I use a different computer name, a different internal ip, email...it is a bit terrifying where this website gets the data from.

Comment: Poor question, but they can fingerprint your machine with many OS and browser level headers. Internal IP is not visible to the website.

Comment: How is this community called?

Answer (score 2):

Your internal IP address is irrelevant.  Its your public IP that is most likely the issue.  Your home or organization only has one public IP.  You can check this [website](https://www.whatismyip.com/) from all your devices and see what it is.  It will be the same on all devices.

Perhaps you should follow the website's code of conduct.

Answer (score 1):

[This website](https://panopticlick.eff.org) is one of many that can show you how easily tracked you can be, even when you think you've changed everything.

Details such as what browser plugins you have, what system fonts are available, your screen resolution, user agent, whether you use a touch device etc, are all available information that can then be used to create a digital 'fingerprint' against you.

Now, whether they use that much information is hard to say, although it's easily possible. They could simply be tracking your public IP address, which may or may not change depending on your ISP.

Here is some [further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) on the subject.